# Query sometimes fails to execute. Is there an alternative?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an automated SQL script that when run executes the following code

```
DROP TABLE INTL_KEY;
CREATE TABLE intl_key AS
SELECT callingpartynumber||calledpartynumber||timeandtimezonestartofcharging AS KEY,a.*   FROM intl a;
```

Basically, its a copy of table **INTL** with a **Primary Key** field.

Immediately after this, the following code is executed.

```
CREATE TABLE intl_code as
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,12)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,11)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,10)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,9)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,8)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,7)=code
UNION
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,6)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,5)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,4)=code
union
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,3)=code
UNION
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,2)=code
UNION
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,1)=code
```

What this section does is create a copy of **INTL_KEY** and add a column with **Code**. The country code from another table **Country_Code** is matched with the dialled number found in **INTL_KEY**.

Example if the dialled number is **00912886098860** it searches for a country code from 91xxxxxxxxxx till 9. Now the problem with this is , suppose a valid code is **912**, it will first be matched with

```
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,3)=code
```

How ever, **91** is also a valid code. Hence it will also be matched with

```
SELECT a.*,b.code FROM intl_key a, country_code b WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,2)=code
```

In order to remove this *duplicate* matching, the next bit of code is

```
DELETE FROM intl_code WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT Min(rowid) FROM intl_code GROUP BY KEY );
```

Keep whichever was matched first, and delete the subsequent matches. This is where the problem occurs. Sometimes, the statement will fail to execute/take extremely long. (Query is run via VPN so sometimes theres a time out,sometimes if the tablespace is too huge it fails to run etc)

I wanted to know if there is a way to optimize what I wish to do. If so, I would appreciate any help with it. Like maybe create a new table with only the rows minimum rowid transferred?

If it helps understanding the scale of things, on an average 300,000 new rows are created each day,with each row having around 50+ fields. (It is the number of international calls for a operator of a particular country per day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can merge these different queries while creating `intl_code` table.

It means you can write like

```
CREATE TABLE intl_code as
SELECT a.*,b.code 
  FROM intl_key a, country_code b 
 WHERE SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,12)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,11)=code 
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,10)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,9)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,8)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,7)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,6)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,5)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,4)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,3)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,2)=code
    or SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,1)=code;
```

so that while fetching data from table join `intl_key a, country_code b` will happen only once.. it will also give the same rows as what you were getting with previous union query.

Basically this query will take time about N times less then what you it was getting with Union.. what I am telling is not a problem with union keyword.. but if you are joining two big tables then you can use multiple condition in place of multiple joins..

try this...

Comment: Thanks! Will this still create duplicates? Because if I understand correctly, if say SubStr(calledpartynumber,3,3)=code is TRUE, then the subsequent statements WILL NOT be evaluated. Hence it would result in only one match (first match)?I.E if 923 and 92 are valid codes, and the dialled number is 00923, then only 923 will be matched; the statement evaluates to TRUE, and other conditions are not checked and the next row is processed. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes .. it will produce the duplicate rows .. you still have to run `delete` command after executing this query.. 

basically this query will join two table .. means m*n rows will be there before applying any condition .. right? so say if code = 923 is there then phone number 009234567 will be satisfy for this code..if code 92 is also exist then one more row will satisfy having phone number 009234567 and code = 92..